# Style text (with CSS) to match borderless font in XD

Tags: css

So I messed up my design in Adobe XD by not using borders on any of the fonts. The result is that in the browser they appear very bold compared to what I designed:

[image: Font comparison]

The above is how I designed the text to look, below what I got. Font is Open Sans.

I'm only familiar with using CSS text-shadows to emulate a positive-sized border on the font. **Is it possible to "remove" the border or stroke in CSS to make the font look like what I designed?** (I'm happy to support only the newest browsers.)

Comment: Are you using any text-shadow? if not try use font-weight:400; hope it helps

Comment: @PiyushVerma Thanks, that emulates a similar effect but is not the same. I was hoping to not use lighter (300 in Open Sans' case, regular is 400) font-weight because I'm using that elsewhere in the design (without stroke, again).

Comment: Just make sure when you design the page font and font-weight should be relevant so that you can use it on html the same way you designed. it will give you the same effect as when you design there are many options to make font crisp, smooth like this.